# Multiple Complex Objects with .net core

Tags: .net, json, api, asp.net-core

I have been trying for ages now but to no avail.

I would like to be able to receive multiple complex objects over Json but for some reason .net core is only binding to the TOP level...

Here is my model used in the controller method:

```
    public class CustomerSendDetailsModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        CampaignMonitorDataModel CampaignData { get; set; }
        CustomerContactInfo CustomerData { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the controller method (NOTE: its only got test data atm)

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> GetData([FromBody]CustomerSendDetailsModel customerDetails)
        {
            return new string[] { "green widget", "red widget" };
        }
```

Now after sending this JSON using PostMan, the only data that gets binded is the string 'name'.

```
{
    "name": "TEST",
    "campaignData": {
        "cId": "direct"
    },
    "customerData": {
        "firstName": "bob"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is not working as it should? :/

I've seen that you can use JObject but was really hoping to be able to do it using this method as its cleaner...

Comment: Did you 100% percent you sending the Post request with `Content-Type: application/json` ? also it will be valuable if you will post `CampaignMonitorDataModel` structure as well.

Comment: Thanks for help, was something small in the end lol -_-

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is quite annoying as this was bugging me with the amount of things i tried...

but basically, it was just because I didn't set the objects to Public in the DTO:

```
    public class CustomerSendDetailsModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        CampaignMonitorDataModel CampaignData { get; set; }
        CustomerContactInfo CustomerData { get; set; }
    }
```

Should be:

```
    public class CustomerSendDetailsModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public CampaignMonitorDataModel CampaignData { get; set; }
        public CustomerContactInfo CustomerData { get; set; }
    }
```